# New Relic not working (gradle + android studio)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, newrelic

I am having problem enabling newrelic monitoring in android app while using gradle and android studio.

I followed exactly instructions adding newrelic to build.gradle, adding code to activity and requesting permissions in manifest:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:3.239.0'
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'

dependencies {
  compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:3.239.0'
}
```

But I am not able to build the app. The result is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.newrelic.agent.compile.RewriterAgent
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:280)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallAgentmain(InstrumentationImpl.java:348)
[newrelic] Error encountered while loading the New Relic agent
com.sun.tools.attach.AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgent(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:103)
    at com.newrelic.agent.android.NewRelicGradlePlugin.apply(NewRelicGradlePlugin.java:47)
    at com.newrelic.agent.android.NewRelicGradlePlugin.apply(NewRelicGradlePlugin.java:15)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultPluginContainer.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultPluginContainer.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.apply(DefaultPluginContainer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$apply.call(Unknown Source)
```

Am I missing something? In Eclipse everything worked fine.

Comment: I think you may need to get in touch with New Relic support directly at support.newrelic.com. I haven't seen an error exactly like this before and would like to investigate (I work at New Relic)

Comment: What gradle version, android gradle plugin versions do you have?

Comment: Gradle 1.9 and com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.3

Comment: Looks like Gradle 1.9 is fully supported, and we should be able to get this working with some consultation with New Relic. Other users have been able to build successfully with com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+

Comment: I have lots of problems too getting NewRelic working - and there support have no clue :(

Comment: Did anyone find any solutions to this issue? I still have the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error when tried to build my project with JDK8. It was solved when I switched to JDK7. New Relic support suspect this is an issue with Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new version of new relic client available. It resolves issues that V3.361.0 had around newer JDKs and proguard. Here's what you should use to resolve the JDK problem.

```
classpath 'com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:3.378.0'
```

Paste this into your build.gradle where you have listed your dependencies. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Yep, it helped, but after clear gradle cache (~/.gradle)